# Remove clear button (grey x) to the right of UISearchBar when cancel button tapped

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, interface-builder

Right, to begin my question, here's some screenies of the problem already solved by the Spotify app:

**Spotify's Step 1:** Standard UISearchBar not in editing mode.

[image: Step 1]

**Spotify's Step 2:** UISearchBar now in editing mode. Search term entered. Cancel button slides in from the right, and the clear button (grey x) appears.

[image: Step 2]

**Spotify's Step 3:** Cancel button pressed; keyboard slides out and the search bar is no longer in editing mode. Search term remains and the **grey x button is now hidden**.

[image: Step 3]

At present, the following code fires off when *my* cancel button is pressed:

```
- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];
}
```

Which results in:

**My Step 3:** Search bar now not in editing mode. Cancel button and keyboard has slid out. Search term remains but so does the grey x.

[image: Problem]

So, my question is this: given that `-resignFirstResponder` (and `-endEditing:`, FYI) does **not** hide the grey x button when a search bar has had text entered into it, how does one hide it?

Thanks again, friends.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The problem is that UISearchBar doesn't expose it's text field, and manages the properties on the text field itself. Sometimes, the values of the properties aren't what you want.

For instance, in my own app, I wanted the keyboard style for my search bar to use the transparent alert style.

My solution was to walk through the subviews of the search bar until you find the text field. You should then be able to set the `clearButtonMode` property, using something like `UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing` as a parameter.

This should make it so that the clear button is only shown while the text field is editing.

You want to do this on `viewDidLoad` or something early, so it's set before you start using it (but after the search bar is initialised.

```
for (UIView *subview in searchBar.subviews)
{
    if ([subview conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)])
    {
        [(UITextField *)subview setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers Jasarien, this seems to be exactly what I need. Unfortunately I'm running into an error with `[subview conformsToProtocol:UITextInputTraits]` which reads: `expected expression before 'UITextInputTraits'`. Do I need to import or conform to anything?

Comment: My bad! Sorry. You need to do `[subview conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)]`

Comment: BTW, did you use an app to make that little annotation on your screenshot, (argh! ->)? If so, what app? It looks useful :)

Comment: Unfortunately that was just a Photoshop brush tool jobbie. Though an annotation app is great idea!

Answer (score 6):

Looks like iOS 7 changed the view hierarchy of UISearchBar, and the text box is deeper in the view (The above solution didn't work for me).  However, modifying the above solution to traverse the whole hierarchy works:

```
[self configureSearchBarView:[self searchBar]];

- (void)configureSearchBarView:(UIView*)view {
    for (UIView *subview in [view subviews]){
        [self configureSearchBarView:subview];
    }
    if ([view conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)]) {
        [(UITextField *)view setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];
    }
}
```

Comment: This could easily be made into a Category on UISearchBar to enable reuse.

Comment: Seems to cause a crash, apparently there's more than one view which conforms to `UITextInputTraits` and that view can not respond to `setClearButtonMode`.

Comment: To prevent the crash I changed it to this: `for (UIView *subview in [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar subviews]){[self configureSearchBarView:subview];}` followed by the `configureSearchBarView:(UIView *)view` method. Seems that in my case it was the searchBar itself which was causing the crash.

Answer (score 6):

I'm building upon the previous answers because I started seeing crashes on iOS 7.1 unless I made the following change. I added an additional call to `respondsToSelector` for each view to make sure that `setClearButtonMode:` can be called. I observed an instance of `UISearchBar` getting passed in, which seems to conform to the `UITextInputTraits` protocol yet does not have the `setClearButtonMode:` selector, so a crash occurred. An instance of `UISearchBarTextField` also gets passed in and is the actual object for which to call `setClearButtonMode:`.

```
- (void)removeClearButtonFromView:(UIView *)view
{
    if (!view)
    {
        return;
    }

    for (UIView *subview in view.subviews)
    {
        [self removeClearButtonFromView:subview];
    }

    if ([view conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)])
    {
        UITextField *textView = (UITextField *)view;
        if ([textView respondsToSelector:@selector(setClearButtonMode:)])
        {
            [textView setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeNever];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to get the textField of the Search Bar

```
UITextField *textField = [searchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;
```

use in - (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar method.

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
 {

UITextField *textField = [searchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;


 }
```

Answer (score 4):

A better way to do this in iOS7 is:

`[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];`

Answer (score 3):

To expand on Jadariens answer if you never want the grey x to appear you need to use the following

```
for (UIView *subview in searchBar.subviews)
{
    if ([subview conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)])
    {
        [(UITextField *)subview setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeNever];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Accepted answer does not work on iOS7+, here is the modified version as a Swift extension

```
extension UIView {
    class func removeClearButton(svs: [UIView]) {
        for sv in svs {
            if let tv = sv as? UITextField where sv.conformsToProtocol(UITextInputTraits) {
                tv.clearButtonMode = .Never
                return
            } else {
                UIView.removeClearButton(sv.subviews)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage

```
UIView.removeClearButton(searchBar.subviews)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hers is a category I wrote that does this

Category

```
@implementation UISearchBar (Additions)

- (void)setClearButtonMode:(UITextFieldViewMode)viewMode {
    UITextField *textField = [self findTextFieldInView:self];
    [textField setClearButtonMode:viewMode];
}

- (UITextField *)findTextFieldInView:(UIView *)view {

    for (UIView *subview in view.subviews) {

        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]] ||
            [subview.class isSubclassOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {

            return (UITextField *)subview;
        }

        UITextField *textField = [self findTextFieldInView:subview];

        if (textField) {
            return textField;
        }
    }

    return nil;
}

@end
```

Usage

```
[searchBar setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a better way than any of the answers here, and you don't have to use private APIs or traverse subviews to do it.

UISearchBar has a built-in API for doing this:

[[UISearchBar setImage:forSearchBarIcon:state]](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBar_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UISearchBar/setImage:forSearchBarIcon:state:)

The SearchBar icon key you want is UISearchBarIconClear, and you want the UIControlStateNormal state. Then give it a clear image for the image, and you're done.

So, it should look like this:

```
[searchBar setImage:clearImage forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconClear state:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

For the (x) icon in searchBar. You can use below delegate method.

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (UIView *subview in _search_bar.subviews)
{
    NSLog(@"%@",subview.subviews);

    for (UIView *subview11 in subview.subviews)
    {
        if ([subview11 conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)])
        {
            [(UITextField *)subview11 setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeNever];
        }
    }

}
```