# setRightView for UISearchBar not working in iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, ios7

I am adding a button in searchbar on right side by this code

```
 [searchtextfield setRightView:customButton];
 [searchtextfield setRightViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
```

It works upto iOS 6,but in iOS 7 i can not see it. Any idea how to accomplish it in iOS 7.

Comment: Try setting tint color of uisearch bar

Comment: It has nothing to do with tint color.

Answer (score -1):

If you have white background then may be its the issue that you can't see search bar, I faced same problem but managed to solve this by adding this code by setting table view background.

```
UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.tableView.bounds];
backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.tableView.backgroundView = backgroundView;
```

Hope it'll help. Thanks.

Comment: I can see search bar, I can not see a button which i set as it's rightView.

Comment: ahh, I think then u see this link"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052343/remove-clear-button-grey-x-to-the-right-of-uisearchbar-when-cancel-button-tapp", hope it'll help. if you like then raise my points.