# Hide Keyboard on clear click in UISearchBar and not backspace to empty text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

I cant seem to find this answer for the manually clearing the UISearchBar with a backspace, only with a cancel button click.  The code below hides the keyboard when the clear button is clicked, but so does the backspace to an empty UISearchBar.  Id like to leave the keyboard open in that scenario since someone might be typing something else.

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar*)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString*)text
{
    [self filterData: text];

    if(text.length == 0)
    {
        [searchBar performSelector:@selector(resignFirstResponder) withObject:nil afterDelay:.1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code includes `if(text.length == 0)` and that means that when the size of the input becomes zero, keyboard is dismissed. However the actual piece should be as follows:

```
- (BOOL) searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Clear is different from Cancel button

Comment: I understand that but consider a scenario where a user tries to reenter the data, it will resign the responder. right?

Comment: Yes, that is why I am asking this question.

Comment: is this what you are looking for ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052343/remove-clear-button-grey-x-to-the-right-of-uisearchbar-when-cancel-button-tapp

Answer (score 0):

My best try on such an issue is to do as suggested here BUT IT DOES NOT WORK WHEN YOU CLICK CLEAR BUTTON :( but I thought it might help you though:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16957073/1465756

Add a tap gesture on your whole view:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                               initWithTarget:self
                               action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}
```

and dismissKeyboard when the view is tapped:

```
  - (void) dismissKeyboard
{
  [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I understand you want to dismiss the keyboard when the user hits Cancel, and you also want to dismiss when the user hits the clear (x) button.

You do not need to implement `searchBar:textDidChange:`.

To detect cancellation, implement `searchBarCancelButtonClicked:`. Here you can trigger `resignFirstResponder`.

To detect clear, adopt `UITextFieldDelegate` and implement `textFieldShouldClear:`. This will be called after the user taps clear, but before the clear occurs. Return `YES` to allow the clear to occur. You may dismiss the keyboard before returning.

Comment: Cancel ONLY works with the Cancel button, this is the clear button, they are totally different.

Comment: Your question is not related to the Cancel button then? You want to resign when they hit the clear button instead? Please update your question - you only mention the cancel button not clear.

Comment: "Hide Keyboard on clear click in UISearchBar and not backspace to empty text"